# Populate dropdown based on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select for Year, and a select for Make, and I want to populate only the makes associated with the years that they have. I can currently populate all data from fitmentData.json, but when i try to filter my selection, i cannot figure out a way to get it working. Currently I have an updateMake() function i believed to be working, but after hacking for about 2 hours, I cannot get a solution.

html

```
  <select name="year" id="year">

  </select>

  <select id="make" name="make">

  </select>
  <select id="model" name="model">

  </select>
```

js

```
 //year
    let yearDropdown = $('#year');
    yearDropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose     
Year</option>');

    //make(brand in json)
    let brandDropdown = $('#make');
    brandDropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose  
Make</option>');

    const url = 'fitmentData.json';

    //append json years in dropdown
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
      $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
        yearDropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value',  
entry.year).text(entry.year));
      })
      //remove year duplicates
      var map = {}
      $('select option').each(function () {
        if (map[this.value]) {
          $(this).remove()
        }
        map[this.value] = true;
      })
      //append json makes in dropdown
      $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
        brandDropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value',  
entry.brand).text(entry.brand));
        updateMake();
      });
      //remove make duplicates
      var map = {}
      $('select option').each(function () {
        if (map[this.value]) {
          $(this).remove()
        }
        map[this.value] = true;
      })

    //updates makes depending on selection
    function updateMake() {
      brandDropdown.empty();
      brandDropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose  
Make</option>');
      if (yearDropdown.value == '1976') {
        var optionArray = ["Yamaha", "Kawasaki"];
        //populate makes depending on year
        for (i = 0; i <= optionArray.length; i++) {
          var newOption = document.createElement('option');
          newOption.innerHTML = optionArray[i];
          brandDropdown.append(newOption);
        }
      }
    }
```

fitmentData.json

```
 [
 {
    "brand": "Yamaha",
    "model": "XT500",
    "year": "1976"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Honda",
    "model": "TL250",
    "year": "1976"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Yamaha",
    "model": "TT500",
    "year": "1976"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Honda",
    "model": "XL125",
    "year": "1976"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Kawasaki",
    "model": "KE125",
    "year": "1976"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Yamaha",
    "model": "YZ175",
    "year": "1976"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Honda",
    "model": "TL125",
    "year": "1976"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Suzuki",
    "model": "RM125",
    "year": "1976"
  }
]
```

Once again, I am able to populate all json data in dropdowns, but the updateMake() function is not working as expected. updateMake() causes the makes to not populate any data at all.

Comment: also, i would like to add, I am only testing for the year 1976 in this code example, but i made sure my selection was 1976 and still no data was populated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `onchange` event on `year` element so when there is a change `updateMake()` is called. Also `yearDropdown.value` won't work as `yearDropdown`is a jQuery object, consider using `yearDropdown.val()` instead:

```js
var data = [{
    "brand": "Yamaha",
    "model": "XT500",
    "year": "1976"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Honda",
    "model": "TL250",
    "year": "1976"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Yamaha",
    "model": "TT500",
    "year": "1976"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Honda",
    "model": "XL125",
    "year": "1976"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Kawasaki",
    "model": "KE125",
    "year": "1976"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Yamaha",
    "model": "YZ175",
    "year": "1976"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Honda",
    "model": "TL125",
    "year": "1976"
  },
  {
    "brand": "Suzuki",
    "model": "RM125",
    "year": "1976"
  }
];



//year
let yearDropdown = $('#year').append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose Year</option>').on('change', function() {
  updateMake();
});

//make(brand in json)
let brandDropdown = $('#make').append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose Make</option>');

//append json years in dropdown
$.each(data, function(key, entry) {
  yearDropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.year).text(entry.year));
})
//remove year duplicates
var map = {}
$('select option').each(function() {
  if (map[this.value]) {
    $(this).remove()
  }
  map[this.value] = true;
})
//append json makes in dropdown
$.each(data, function(key, entry) {
  brandDropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.brand).text(entry.brand));
  updateMake();
});
//remove make duplicates
var map = {}
$('select option').each(function() {
  if (map[this.value]) {
    $(this).remove()
  }
  map[this.value] = true;
})

//updates makes depending on selection
function updateMake() {
  brandDropdown.empty();
  brandDropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose Make</option>');
  if (yearDropdown.val() == '1976') {
    var optionArray = ["Yamaha", "Kawasaki"];
    //populate makes depending on year
    for (i = 0; i < optionArray.length; i++) {
      var newOption = document.createElement('option');
      newOption.innerHTML = optionArray[i];
      brandDropdown.append(newOption);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="year" id="year">

</select>

<select id="make" name="make">

</select>
<select id="model" name="model">

</select>
```

Comment: worked! thanks for the help. one thing though, i am getting a select option that says undefined. Could that be because of my for loop?

Comment: @DylanT yes, you might want to change it from `<=` to `<`

Comment: I believe i fixed that by adding optionArray.length - 1 in my for loop. Pretty sure by not adding the minus 1 i just went one index too far..

Comment: @DylanT yes you could do that too